# Nuget restore not working using nuget command task error azure pipeline

Tags: asp.net, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I am trying to build an app using msbuild 14 and I am getting this error while using nuget restore command. Hav used both 5.x and 6.x nuget version but I can't figure whats causing this

C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\5.11.5\x64\nuget.exe restore D:\a\1\s\x\packages.config -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_17578.config
File 'D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_17578.config' does not exist.

The project I am using doesn't have a nuget.config file

Az pipeline add this switch -ConfigFile D:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_17578.config itself I have nothing to do with this

Answer (score 0):

When you use `restore` command for the nuget task, **Feeds to use** is required(doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-command-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)).

[image]

I can reproduce the same error with you when no nuget.config file exists in source code, and if `feeds to use` is not specified.

Please tick option **Use packages from NuGet.org** as below, it will check public nuget package instead.

[image]

Or if you have dependencies in the project actually, please add the related config or feed needed.

Comment: Hi @TechStack，may i know if it works? let me know if you have any queries.